# How to change the name of executable entry point from main to something else?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld, elf

I'm trying to compile third party source code using gcc 4.8 on Ubuntu Linux (12.04 x64) with a lot of utilities and test applications where executable entry point is not called `main`. Don't ask me why - I don't know the answer.

Linker of course complains:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is it possible to force linker to use another method as the entry point? I tried to use these linker options with gcc but neither of them worked:
`-Wl,-eWhatever` or `-Wl,--entry=Whatever` or `-Wl,-e,Whatever`. All ended with the same error.

Comment: I believe that _start() expects your program to have main(). You'd need to compile with -nostdlib to bypass the bootstrapping code.

Comment: I suspect the utilities and test applications may have been designed as libraries (for utilities it's obvious --- as for test applications, to be compiled with a "master" program that runs them in sequence).

Comment: @Tim Čas: In that scenario OP should compile it as shared library (`gcc -shared` flag), with PIC relocatable (by `-fpic`, or `-fPIC` if your CPU can't afford the former). Surely my answer make no sense then.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: Well, your answer *does* make sense, as it explains *why* this doesn't work, and why he should just use `main()`. Whether it's *useful* or not depends on the context though, which OP does not provide (at least not enough to determine which approach should be used). Given what we've been, well, given, I think it's a good answer.

Comment: When building boot code for an embedded system running on bare metal, I usually bring `_start()` and related hardware vector entry points into my project. This is needed especially if the DRAM controller requires initialization before there is memory to hold a stack, for instance. I often rename `main()` in that case to emphasize the special nature of that code. When the boot code is loading and launching separately linked application code, I allow that code to use `main()` and use mostly standard CRT initializations.

Comment: There's no good reason for user-space code running under an OS to not enter in `main()`, however. So the conjecture that there is a framework executable that has `main()` and that this code is really a plugin of some kind makes sense. Especially for a test framework. Imagine test cases being `.DLL` or `.so` containing a `runtest()` function. The framework could load `*.dll` and call each `runtest()` in turn.

Comment: @TimČas: Unfortunately they are not designed as libraries.

Comment: @RBerteig: Thanks for explanation. It may actually be the case because it is some cross platform API with utilities and tests to verify port. It is supposed to work on almost everything including some obscure 16bit embedded systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As by C Standard, the *hosted environment* (that I guess is your case as/if you want to use standard library headers*) forces you to keep with `main` function. From C11 §5.1.2.2.1/p1 (emphasis mine):

> The function called at program startup is named `main`. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It **shall be
>   defined** with a return type of int and with no parameters:
>
> `int main(void) { /* ... */ }`
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as
>   argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to the
>   function in which they are declared):
>
> `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`
>
> or equivalent;10) or in some other
>   implementation-defined manner.

There are two options that I can think of to bypass `main` function requirement in your situation:

1. Create separate object file (that is, by `gcc -c`) with `main` symbol, that just (declares and) calls (i.e. wraps) your custom entry point (possibly passing through `argc` and `argv` invocation arguments). This would make linker happy and is as simple as adding single makefile rule.
2. Compile your program as `gcc -DWhatever=main`. This essentially replaces every instance of `Whatever` preprocessing token by `main`, so linker thinks of `Whatever` as "proper" main function.

<sup>* some headers must be available in freestanding environment too, such as `<stddef.h>` and `<float.h>`, see §4/p6 for full list of them.</sup>

Here is some basic ilustration of both options. Each assumes, that `foo.c` is as following:

#### `foo.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    printf("foo\n");
}
```

#### First method:

#### `main.c`

```
/* declare an entry point */
void foo(void);

/* define main as wrapper function */
int main(void)
{
    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Compile & run:

```
$ gcc -c main.c
$ gcc foo.c main.o
$ ./a.out
foo
```

#### Second method:

```
$ gcc -Dfoo=main foo.c 
$ ./a.out
foo
```

Some things may require more tweaking, but I hope you catch the idea.

Comment: Of course, an implementation of the standard often has facilities available that it used to implement this, which can also be used to implement other languages with other assumptions. GCC supports FORTRAN, Pascal, Ada, and other languages, so `ld` does have the ability to create executable files that lack `main()` entirely. Misusing that capability with C code is likely possible, but there will be pitfalls if you don't arrange to initialize the runtime library properly. The pitfalls are deeper for C++ code.

Comment: @Grzegorz: Thanks for explanation. I initially expected that it is actually a preprocessor macro and when I found it isn't I had your option 2 as a backup plan.

Comment: @RBerteig: Thanks for explaining why that linker option does not work with C. It was my follow up question ...